# How to use a different font CSS color for all Internet Explorer browser versions?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I have a WordPress theme that uses the [HTML5 Bolierplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate). As well, I use the "Edit CSS" module of the [Jetpack plugin](http://jetpack.me/) to make modifications and additions to the theme's CSS.

Through the "Edit CSS" module of Jetpack, I have defined some 3 dimensional CSS text shadows for various WordPress widget headings.

```
.example-widget h3{   
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9, 0 3px 0 #bbb, 0 4px 0 #b9b9b9, 
    0 5px 0 #aaa, 0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 
    0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 
    0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 
    0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

The problem, on Internet Explorer, the 3D text shadow is not supported (At least up to IE9. I have not tested on IE10) and the white font does not work with the very light colored background. On IE, I need a color of `#444` to replace the 3D text effect.

The Bolierplate defines the following in the `<head>`, but I can't seem to figure out how to define a font color for all versions of IE:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

To get it out of the way now, I'm sure I will be asked to justify why I put this question here, rather than on [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) - The reason, they would tell me this is not a WordPress specific question, although I wonder if the Jetpack "Edit CSS" module may come into play, as the CSS in the module is loaded after ALL style sheets are defined in the theme.

Comment: IE10 does support `text-shadow` :)

Comment: Thanks. I just realized I had IE9, went to DL IE10, but it is only for Windows 8.

Comment: IE10 Release Preview has been made available for Windows 7 - you can grab it [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/ie-10-release-preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two quick ways of doing this.

**Feature Detection - [See Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). <-- preferred option**

This won't check the browser version, just whether or not the browser supports `text-shadow`. You call in the Modernizr script at the top of the page. Then you create a class like:

```
.example-widget {
    color: blue;
}

.no-text-shadow .example-widget {
    color: red;
}
```

**Conditional Comments**

My favourite way of doing this, because it lets you keep all your CSS in one file.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js ie lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>         <html class="no-js ie ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9|!IE]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then you use:

```
.example-widget {
   color: blue;
}

.ie .example-widget {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: In this case you're simply modifying what HTML5 Boilerplate already does to add an `ie` class. The problem with this modification is that *all* browsers will receive the `ie` class, because the `<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->` chunk is designed to be read by IE9 as well as all other browsers.

Comment: The last conditional comment should start with `<!--[if !IE]><!-->`, then you're set.

Comment: @BoltClock Given IE10, would it be more accurate to say `<!--[if gt IE 9|!IE]>`? Would that still work?

Comment: That is not necessary, because IE10 no longer supports conditional comments - it reads them just like any other comment.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'd misinterpreted. Yes, that should still work. You can even remove the `|!IE` if you want, since IE9 cannot possibly match `gt IE 9`.

Comment: I left it in - that way it says exactly where it's applied, so doesn't assume any knowledge of the developer about the rules of conditional comments.

Comment: Thanks! I swear I tried this method as well, but I was pretty tired, so I probably mistyped something

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your styles in an ie conditional -

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Then on your all-ie-only.css stylehseet you just want something like -

```
body {
    color: red;
}
```

You may also need to create overrides for any elements that override the above. For example -

```
.example-widget h3 { 
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Scratch my previous comment. The funny thing about this is that IE10 coincidentally supports `text-shadow` *and* does not support conditional comments, so you'll have a clean cut between IE10 and all previous versions.

Comment: I still haven't fired up IE10 (think I'm burying my head in the sand).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Internet Explorer conditional comment**.  Add the conditional comment to the `<head>` tag.  The following will apply to all versions of Internet Explorer that understands the conditional comment:

```
<!--[if IE ]>
  <link href="iecss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
```

In the css file (in this example it would be iecss.css) add the following class

```
.example-widget h3 {
   color: #444
}
```

Internet Explorer would use this class (with color: #444) instead of the original `.example-widget` class that has the 3d effect.

For more information about Internet Explorer conditional comments, see this article:
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/conditionalcomments